# Why my view has width and height 0

Tags: java, android

Hi I am using this code

```
View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null, false);
int width=v.getWidth();
int height=v.getHeight();
```

but the height and width returns zero, Why is it not working , how to get the height and widht of my view. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Eric thanks I haven't seached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Width and Height of the view can be measured after drawing to the screen`. Your inflatted view doesn't yet drawn on the screen
so if you want get height and width 
try this.

```
View contentview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null, false);
contentview.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
int width = contentview.getMeasuredWidth();
int height = contentview.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Answer (score 1):

getHeight() and getWidth() return 0 when component are not drawn. 
So all you need to draw the component and get the measurements of the drawn component.